# Want to avoid creating default tables of ASP.NET Identity 2.0 those are not being used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have created default MVC5 application with Individual User Account in `Visual Studio 2015`. 
When I run the application and register an user, it will add 
   a database with the given connection string in `web.config`.
   In which there are following tables created automatically,

```
AspNetUsers     
AspNetRoles       
AspNetUserClaims   
AspNetUserLogins    
AspNetUserRoles
```

and there is only one table `(AspNetUsers)` containing user information that I have registered and other tables are empty.

So I want to remove those four tables that I didn't want to use, these are

```
AspNetRoles       
AspNetUserClaims   
AspNetUserLogins    
AspNetUserRoles
```

When I removed those tables from the database, I got error saying `invalid object AspNetRoles`, etc.

Please anyone suggest me to remove these tables without any error.

Thanks.

Comment: That will be painful - you will need to implement your own custom UserStore, RoleStore, etc. that don;t use those tables.

Comment: Steve, Is there not any other way to achieve this?

Comment: There is always another way. You are going to need some knowledge about how the pieces fit together and what the dependencies are, but UserManager is fairly integral to identity. http://johnatten.com/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2-0-customizing-identity-models-and-implementing-role-based-authorization/#Add-a-Vanilla-Users-Role-as-a-Default-in-ApplicationDbInitializer

Comment: Effort in overriding default implementation is far greater than having 4 empty tables in the database - not worth doing in my experience.

Comment: I agree with @trailmax, but if you really want to do this, try looking up more information on the ASP.NET Identity page here http://www.asp.net/identity